# libgdx won't draw sprite or animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx, draw

it seems as though i cannot get the draw method to work???
it seems as though the bullet.draw(batcher) 
does not work and i cannot understand why as the bullet is a sprite.
i have made a Sprite[] and added them as animation.
could that be it?

i tried

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), bullet.getOriginX() / 2, bullet.getOriginY() / 2, bullet.getWidth(), bullet.getHeight(), 1, 1, bullet.getRotation());
```

but that dont work, the only way it draws is this

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY());
```

below is the code.

// this is in a Asset Class

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("SpriteN1.png"));
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);

bullet1 = new Sprite(texture, 380, 350, 45, 20);
bullet1.flip(false, true);

bullet2 = new Sprite(texture, 425, 350, 45, 20);
bullet2.flip(false, true);

Sprite[] bullets = { bullet1, bullet2 };
bulletAnimation = new Animation(0.06f, bullets);
bulletAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

// this is the GameRender class

```
public class GameRender() {
private Bullet bullet;
private Ball ball;

public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
myWorld = world;
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(true, 480, 320);

batcher = new SpriteBatch();
// Attach batcher to camera
batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

// Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
initGameObjects();
initAssets();
}

private void initGameObjects() {
ball = GameWorld.getBall();
bullet = myWorld.getBullet();
scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
}

private void initAssets() {
ballAnimation = AssetLoader.ballAnimation;
bulletAnimation = AssetLoader.bulletAnimation;
}

public void render(float runTime) {

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batcher.begin();
// Disable transparency 
// This is good for performance when drawing images that do not require
// transparency.
batcher.disableBlending();

// The ball needs transparency, so we enable that again.
batcher.enableBlending();


batcher.draw(AssetLoader.ballAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),         ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());

batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(),     bullet.getY());

// End SpriteBatch
batcher.end();
}
}
```

// this is the gameworld class

```
public class GameWorld {

public static Ball ball;
private Bullet bullet;
private ScrollHandler scroller;

public GameWorld() {
ball = new Ball(480, 273, 32, 32);
bullet = new Bullet(10, 10);
scroller = new ScrollHandler(0);
}

public void update(float delta) {
ball.update(delta);
bullet.update(delta);
scroller.update(delta);
}

public static Ball getBall() {
return ball;
}

public ScrollHandler getScroller() {
return scroller;
}

public Bullet getBullet() { 
return bullet;
}
}
```

is there anyway so make the sprite work?

i am adding the bullet class to see if there could be something wrong there.

```
public class Bullet extends Sprite {

public static final float BULLET_HOMING = 6000;
public static final float BULLET_SPEED = 300;
private Vector2 velocity;
private float lifetime;

public Bullet(float x, float y) {
    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    setPosition(x, y);
}

public void update(float delta) {
    float targetX = GameWorld.getBall().getX();
    float targetY = GameWorld.getBall().getY();
    float dx = targetX - getX();
    float dy = targetY - getY();

    float distToTarget = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    dx /= distToTarget;
    dy /= distToTarget;
    dx *= BULLET_HOMING;
    dy *= BULLET_HOMING;
    velocity.x += dx * delta;
    velocity.y += dy * delta;

    float vMag = (float) Math.sqrt(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y);
    velocity.x /= vMag;
    velocity.y /= vMag;
    velocity.x *= BULLET_SPEED;
    velocity.y *= BULLET_SPEED;

    Vector2 v = velocity.cpy().scl(delta);
    setPosition(getX() + v.x, getY() + v.y);
    setOriginCenter();
    setRotation(velocity.angle());
    lifetime += delta;
    setRegion(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(lifetime));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post images too?

Comment: post images where? on the game? then yes but they are TextureRegions and you cannot rotate textureRegions. there is a way but it is too hard for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keyframes are kept in an array called bullets, but when you call the Animation constructor you pass something called 'aims' as the second argument. You should try instead passing 'bullets', as in:

```
bulletAnimation = new Animation(0.06f,bullets);
```

You shouldn't have a problem with using a Sprite[] as the Sprite class extends TextureRegion I think.

------ OP fixed the typo and still didn't work------

I think the problem will be with the origin arguments of the `batcher.draw()`call. The position of the Sprite is relative to the origin of the SpriteBatch's co-ordinate system, and the origin of the Sprite is relative to this position (i.e. the bottom-left corner of the Sprite rectangle). To get an origin in the center of the Sprite, i think originX should be width/2 and originY should be height/2. So try:

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),bullet.getX(),bullet.getY(), bullet.getWidth()/2,bullet.getHeight()/2,bullet.getWidth(),bullet.getHeight(),1,1,bullet.getRotation());
```

Because if your getOriginX/Y methods return origins relative to the SpriteBatcher's co-ordinate system(the screen co-ordinates), then your Sprites could be rotating and scaling around some ridiculous origin and end up being drawn off-screen.

I hope I'm right and it's problem solved.

----- OP posted further code, the 'bullet' class-----

When you call `bullet.getWidth()` and `bullet.getHeight()` in your draw method, these will return 0.0f because you haven't specified values for them. Remember the Sprites you are actually drawing are bullet1 and bullet2 from your AssetLoader class. Try setting bullet's width and height with:

```
setSize(AssetLoader.bullet1.getWidth(), AssetLoader.bullet1.getHeight());
```

in your bullet constructor.

I don't think you need to use `setRegion()` in your bullet class either, again, because the Sprites you're actually drawing are bullet1 and 2.

fingers crossed.

Comment: sorry that was a typo i am passing bullets but it still wont draw if i use bullet.draw(batcher);

Comment: I can't figure out what you do with bullet.getOriginX/Y either, why do you half this value? surely the function returns the origin for scaling/rotation in the first place? what do these functions return?

Comment: i dont know i was told to try that but even without that it does not draw.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have tried that method and the bullet will not draw on the canvas. I tried just using one single png sprite and it still wont rotate so its either not being drawn on the screen right or their is something missing in the bullet class. HOW TO ROTATE THE IMAGE VIA maths is the solution. Thank you again

Comment: Hi ArthurBrown i added the bullet class maybe there is something there that could cause this????

Comment: You sir are a GENIUS it is getting better. now the bullet is facing the wrong way :( i am going to try and fix it and if you could just a little more i will keep you in mind as soon as i am able to rep hard you will be getting them. as you helped me the most and i dont know how to show my appreciation. again Thank you i got some results. Just need to try and get the bullet to face the right way. Thank you so much Arthur. johnny

Comment: the bullet is facing LEFT <--- when it is drawn as that is how the sprite is, and now it is doing what it should do thank you again Arthur. but now the bullet is not facing the target. it is backwards. do i have to set anything for it to face the target? how can i make it face the target? Thank you

Comment: done it to a point i cant believe it THANK YOU ARTHUR BROWN you sir are einstein of libgdx more programming. i fixed the sprite as now it flips when needed. oh what i relief Ahhhhhhhhhhhh Thank you again

Comment: took down my original comment as it was not needed. glad it worked out

Comment: please remember to mark the answer as accepted so that this does not appear in the "unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 0):

try and change the update method to this

```
Vector2 target = new Vector2(GameWorld.getBall().getX(), GameWorld.getBall().getY());
    target.sub(getX(), getY());
    target.nor().scl(BULLET_HOMING);
    velocity.add(target.scl(delta));
    velocity.nor().scl(BULLET_SPEED);

    Vector2 v = velocity.cpy().scl(delta);
    translate(v.x, v.y);

    setOriginCenter();
    setRotation(velocity.angle());
```

that should clean your code a little